# How to find all my purchased soundtracks in Steam?

Tags: steam

For some games, the corresponding "Original Soundtracks" (OST) are sold separately and can be bought and downloaded without the base game, and are listed as a separate category in Library (e.g. [Baba Is You Soundtrack](https://store.steampowered.com/app/955710/Baba_Is_You_Soundtrack/)). However, some other games bundle their OSTs as a DLC (e.g. [ibb & obb - Soundtrack](https://store.steampowered.com/app/299190/ibb__obb__Soundtrack_by_Kettel/)) and are not listed separately from the base game. How can I efficiently find all OSTs from my Steam Library that are considered as a DLC and not standalone content?

Answer (score 1):

Isolating it to DLC-only... Why do you want that?

If it's just to keep file sizes down, you can download it, pull it out of the folder, then delete it. There's no DRM in that sorta way.

---

Okay, found [one](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1153021/Airis_Adventure_OST/) I can test with.

Yeah, getting it to appear... Haven't figured it out yet...

Comment: My PC's disk size is not a concern for me, but finding those "DLC"s is. I can't even list them normally.

Comment: Well your example isn't a DLC. It doesn't show "This content requires the base game on Steam in order to play" and is categorized as "standalone additional content".

Comment: Oh, you're right! I got confused by the "DLC" banner! ... It's hard to find some that fulfill your requirements...